# jQuery: Live update of input with replace of random selected keyword

Tags: jquery, random, replace

I'm looking to create a (random, update by `keyup`) behavior with a keywords text input:

Each time I update a keywords input (words, separated with ", "), I update a `post_title` text input, but this `post_title` already has content and can accept an updated keyword only by replacing `{{keyword}}` (and keeping the rest of the text intact).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7yLqb/1/

The `slug` currently updates as needed (randomly and each time I update the keywords) as no replace of `{{keyword}}` is needed, but `post_title` needs to maintain its content, while updating `{{keyword}}` each time I modify the keywords input.

Does this makes any sense?

JS

```
$(function () {

    $('#keywords').bind('keyup', function () {

        var items = $(this).val().split(', ');
        var keywords_value = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

        var post_title_value = $('#post_title').val();
        var post_title_value_replaced = post_title_value.replace('{{keyword}}', keywords_value);
        $('#post_title').val(post_title_value_replaced);

        var slug = keywords_value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '-').toLowerCase().replace(/--+/g, '-');
        $('#slug').val(slug);

    });

});
```

Comment: give an example input, and the result you expect to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the template (the value from post_title) separately so that you don't lose the location of `{{keyword}}` when you change it's value.

```
$(function () {
    var titleTemplate = $("#post_title").val();
    $('#keywords').bind('keyup', function () {

        var items = $(this).val().split(', ');
        var keywords_value = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

        //var post_title_value = $('#post_title').val();
        var post_title_value_replaced = titleTemplate.replace('{{keyword}}', keywords_value);
        $('#post_title').val(post_title_value_replaced);

        var slug = keywords_value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '-').toLowerCase().replace(/--+/g, '-');
        $('#slug').val(slug);

    });

});
```